# Snowflake deduplicate within Stream slow

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using snowpipe to ingest files from S3 into a base table, I then have a task that will consume the append only stream on this base table and merge into a "Latest view" table.

For an individual set of files I won't have any merge conflicts, but if my stream contains multiple sets of files I can have duplicate keys. To avoid this I am using a window over the stream data to pick the latest for each key, but the performance can be pretty bad, even with a 4XL WH since the stream could have 100sM rows.
Is there any way to limit the data read from the stream (e.g. next 10,000 rows) so that the window is smaller and hence the dedupe is faster?

Or any alternative approaches? Ideally it would be great to provide an order by column to resolve conflicts...
I don't think I can guarantee to not have conflicts in the stream, but right now the impact of the conflict resolution is poor performance of my tasks even though 99% of the time I wont have conflicts.

Comment: Can you please share some examples? I once did exactly the same (deduplicating records by using tasks and streams)

Comment: So files are dropped into S3, using snowpipe to ingest them automatically into "history" table.
I have a task that reads the change stream from this history table and merges into a final table.
This all works, but to prevent getting the NON-DETERMINISTIC MERGE error I have to de-dupe within the stream using a window function & row_number()
This is slow since I can be windowing over hundreds of millions of records.

Comment: Is the "history table" already in columnar format or is there one single column with the json in it?

Comment: Have you considered running the Task that consumes the Stream more frequently so that it applies to a smaller dataset and therefore runs faster? Also, I would make sure that an After Task runs to Delete rows from the Source table that have been processed. Another option I would consider is creating multiple Streams to be consumed, whereby the Source table can be orizzontally partitioned in a logical sense (e.g. there's a column Continent that allows me to build 7 Streams one for each Continent) and consumed by different Tasks.

Comment: Both tables are in the same format
The task runs every 5 mins, the problem is that as its consuming from a stream that is populated by snowpipe, sometimes there is a lot of data and the task runs for longer than 5 mins (and thus there is even more data on the stream for the next task)